# How to search content from custom file extensions in Windows 7 non-indexed

Tags: search, full-text-search, windows-7-x64, file-extension

I can search content from .txt, .docx, etc 
but having other non windows extensions is rejected by windows search.
I am not using Indexing service since I am searching on a network share, which cannot be indexed AFAIK.
I went into folder options and selected "Always search file names and contents" which works but only on common windows extensions.

Comment: OK I have downloaded Google Desktop Search and it seems to know how to index remove file shares.

Answer (score 0):

To search custom file formats, you'd need to run your own indexer. See [Apache SOLR](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for one possibility.